# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on string in view-thread.php:46 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown on line 46

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error and can't figure out what to do.

```
<section class="home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="forum1" style="margin-top:200px;">
                <h4>Content:</h4>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM threads";
                    while ($row = $query->fetch_array())
                    {
                        $rows[] = $row;
                    }
                    foreach ($rows as $row)
                    {
                        ?>
                            <div class="clean-blog-post">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                                                        <h3><?php echo $row["title"];?></h3>
                                                        <div class="info"><span class="text-muted"><?php echo $row["date"], " by "; echo $row["username"];?></span></div>
                                                        <p><?php echo mb_strimwidth($row["content"], 0, 100, '...');?></p>
                                                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" role="button" href="blog-post.php?postid=<?php echo $row["postid"];?>">Read More</a>
                                                        <?php
                                                        if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))
                                                        {
                                                            if ($_SESSION["username"] == $row["username"])
                                                            {?>
                                                                <a class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm' role='button' href='remove-post.php?postid=<?php echo $row["postid"];?>'>Remove</a>
                                                                <a class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm' role='button' href='edit-post.php?postid=<?php echo $row["postid"];?>'>Edit</a><?php
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        if (isset($_SESSION["admin"]))
                                                        {
                                                            if ($_SESSION["admin"] == 1)
                                                            {?>
                                                                <a class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm' role='button' href='remove-post.php?postid=<?php echo $row["postid"];?>'>Remove</a><?php
                                                            }
                                                            if ($_SESSION["username"] == $row["username"])
                                                            {?>
                                                                <a class='btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm' role='button' href='edit-post.php?postid=<?php echo $row["postid"];?>'>Edit</a><?php
                                                            }
                                                        }?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div><?php
                                }
                            
                        ?>
                    }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing the `mysqli query()` function.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM threads"; 
$run = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($row = $run->fetch_array())
{
    // todo
}
```